# How to implement/use dynamic type in Android's material design

Tags: android, material-design, typography

In Google's documentation of their new [material design](http://www.google.com/design/spec) a wast article about [typography](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html) can be found. In these specs there is a short section about 'large type and dynamic type'.

Does anyone know how this should and could be implemented? I was hoping to find more details online or in the source code but couldn't find any pointers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't believe this doesn't have an answer yet...the docs imply dynamic type can be used and it scales up or down preset, useful values

Comment: They probably only added it to their document as part of the material design 'theory' without adding native support to Lollipop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think they are working on it. If you check [their blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/) you can see some new features, but not all. The material design project is so big and has so much features that google can't provide them for development at one time.

If you have a look at [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) and [this](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2015/06/more-material-design-with-topeka-for_16.html) site you can see that google is working on it to bring new features. Typography should be on the roadlist.

Comment: Update: This is now possible https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview